# Compare CSV file with Neo4j results

Tags: java, csv, neo4j

I have a task to compare an oracle export(CSV like format but not comma as delimiter) with a neo4j export.

One oracle csv file(can have milion of rows) format is like:

```
OBJECT_ID|'¦'|NAME|'¦'|SITE_LOCATION|'¦'|PARENT_ID|'¦'|LOCATION_CODE
9144735089013188062|¦|00|¦|9144735080313909184|¦|9144735085613119290|¦|O2GB
```

Here OBJECT_ID is unique and data is sorted by it.

1. Now my first approach was to create from cypher db a similar csv using some java code saving in a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` variable the results of a cypher query like :

> {"loc1"={ObjectId="9144735079813886326", NAME="locationName",
>   SITE_LOCATION="Location", ParentId="9144735080313909184"},
>       "loc2"={ObjectId="9144735079813886326", NAME="locationName", SITE_LOCATION="Location", ParentId="9144735080313909184"}}

and export it to a csv.

Then I have to load both csvs back to java in order to compare them and create some kind of report in which I need to have the name of the key if the value from the 2 csvs does not match.

2. Second approach that I can think of is to load the oracle csv into a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` or some datatype and compare it with my cypher results thus skipping the neo4j to csv conversion.

Would it be possible to load in parallel from each csv line by line in a similar Map of something without the need of loading both csvs at the same time into memory?

What would be the best approach of this?

Comment: Why do this through exports?  Consider reading a chunk of records from Oracle and seeing if there are related objects in neo4j (or the other way around).

Comment: The Oracle dump is done anyway, I thought I would have more flexibility on building the report, processing everything in java than on db side but I will turn on this approach on comparing the dbs themselves

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should load your CSV's to any Relational DB (maybe the Oracle, that you already have) and compare them using SQL queries?

Answer (score -1):

Are the JSON files the same? You could just use a diff tool like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)

Comment: The files are CSV like with different delimiter and yes, they are the same, I cannot use any tool for this, as I have to stick with components which are approved by the company.